# Oracle trigger insert other table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, triggers, insert

I have 2 tables which are `my_school` and `my_class`

And "`my_school`" table has '`info_id`' column and also "`my_class`" table has '`info_id`' then I want to get a query that automatically generate "`info_id`" then I found solution..

Here are my working TRIGGER on "`my_school`" table...

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER info_id

 before insert on my_direction 

 for each row

 begin 

 if :NEW.WAY_ID is null then 

 :NEW.WAY_ID := example_id_seq.nextval; 

 end if;

 end;
```

---

It works and it's generating auto id when inserting value. 
But now how to get this trigger do it on "my_class" table when users insert value on my_school's table then take id with "my_class" table's "info_id" column same time?

Comment: This is trigger on my_direction table not on my_school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create trigger on `my_school` table to update `info_id` similar to that you have explained and while inserting records, use returning into clause.

Declare a variable to store returned value, for example

```
v_info_id number(9);
```

And use it in returning into clause

```
insert into my_school(column.......list) 
values (values........list)
RETURNING info_id INTO v_info_id;
```

Use `v_info_id` in your program to insert value of `info_id` into another tables.